# Assign value to select in Laravel Collectives

Tags: laravel

I am not sure if I do anything right here, and I cannot really find any documentation about this. Good documentation advice would also be nice. I try to fill a select from Laravel Collectives but I am not sure how to set the id field correctly because right now it is just returning the position.
So I pass a table from my controller:

```
$stuff_types = DB::table('companies')->where('active', '1')->pluck('name','id');
```

and call this in my view:

```
{{Form::select('stuff_types', array_merge(array('default' => 'Please Select'), $stuff_types->all('name', 'id')), null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>"order-type"]) }}
```

I would now like to assign what is the displayed name and what is the value behind so that I can call it in javascript. If I do it without Collectives, it looks like this:

```
<select name="categories" id="categories" class="form-control">    
                                        <option value="-5">Pleace Select</option>                                    
                                    @foreach($positions as $sector)
                                        @if ($sector->id == 2 || $sector->id == 3)
                                            <option value="{{ $sector->id }}">{{ $sector->name }}</option>
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
```

Also can someone give me a hint how to verify an array instead of checking each value by one:

```
$sector->id == 2 || $sector->id == 3
```

Thanks in advance

Stephan

---

Update 2019-08-14

After the help of nakov, we could figure out the problem and solve it like this:

Option1:

Controller

```
$stuff_types = DB::table('companies')->where('active', '1')->pluck('name','id');
$stuff_types->prepend('Please Select', '');
```

View:

```
{{Form::select('stuff_types', $stuff_types, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>"order-type"]) }}
```

Option 2:

Controller

```
$stuff_types = DB::table('companies')->where('active', '1')->pluck('name','id')->toArray();
```

View:

```
{{Form::select('stuff_types', ['' => 'Please Select'] + $stuff_types, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>"order-type"]) }}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your question here.. are you trying to pre-select an option based on a previous value, or what are you trying to do?

Comment: This is something I want to do in a further step. Right now I just would like to know how to use the laravel collectives select to deposit the value of the table and not a random one. In HTML you can do it with <option value="{{ $sector->id }}">{{ $sector->name }}</option> but don’t know how to do this with the other syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in the element should be the array of the elements, so you already are passing it the right way from your controller, it should be an array like this:

```
[1 => 'Title 1', 2 => 'Title 2' ....]
```

So what you need is this instead:

```
{{Form::select('stuff_types', array_merge(array('default' => 'Please Select'), $stuff_types), null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>"order-type"]) }}
```

just delete the call to `all` :)

The third parameter which is `null` at the moment, is the value that you need pre-selected.

-- EDIT

In your controller add this instead:

```
$stuff_types = DB::table('companies')->where('active', '1')->pluck('name','id')->toArray();
```

And use the above code for the select that I've shared.

Comment: Unfortunately, this return an error:
"array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array (View: /var/www/resources/views/test.blade.php)"

Even after I change my controller from
$stuff_types = DB::table('companies')->where('active', '1')->pluck('name','id');

to get();

Comment: I think that `pluck` returns an array, try chaining `toArray()` instead of `get`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand or I am just incapable. I removed the pluck from the controller, or the all method in the view but nothing works. I am not really sure, but I only want to grab two columns from a database, show the name in the select and put the id as value.

Comment: @Stephan you are not incapable, we've all been in this place. So take a look at my edit above.

Comment: It is still not working. The value is still assigned to the loaded order and not to the id value from the database table. Somehow in the select is the value mapping missing.

Comment: When you inspect the element in the browser do you see the ids? I really don't understand how it can send an order id to the server..

Comment: When I inspect the element in the browser, I see following outcome:

<select id="order-type" name="stuff_types" class="form-control valid" aria-invalid="false">

<option value="default">Please Select</option>

<option value="0">ONE</option>

<option value="1">TWO</option>

<option value="2">THREE</option></select>

But the value of ONE should be 1, and so on

Comment: @Stephan can you try `dd($stuff_types);` in your controller, and share here what is the data that you get. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: This returns the correct array:
array:3 [▼
  1 => "ONE"
  2 => "TWO"
  4 => "FOUR"
]

Three is disabled through a where condition in the select:
$stuff_types = DB::table('companies')->where('active', '1')->pluck('name','id')->toArray();

Comment: Can you please try without the `array_merge` so just pass, `$stuff_types` and check if merging is what resets the ids..

Comment: You are right; removing the array_merge fixes the wrong id.
I updated the initial post. Thanks a lot